# d3 circle onclick event not firing

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg

I'm starting with svg and I have created the following markup.

```
<svg width="500" height="600" class="graph-container">
  <g>
    <rect x="150" y="190" height="50" width="200" rx="30" ry="30" nodeId="1" children="3" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(68, 68, 68);"></rect>
    <text x="250" y="220" text-anchor="middle" fill="#444" style="font-size: 24px;">root</text>

  </g>

</svg>
```

I have added a small circle into the larger rectangle through d3js.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var node = d3.select('g');
var addchild = node.append("circle")
            .attr("cx",320)
            .attr("cy",210)
            .attr("r",10)
            .attr("class","addchild")
            .style("fill","none")
            .style("stroke","#444");

            addchild.on("click", function() {
                alert("on click");
            });; 

});
```

but the click event is not firing.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmmbzk3a/) of the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default you can only click on the parts of a shape that are actually drawn. Since the fill is "none" in your shape it doesn't respond to clicks. The stroke does but that's very thin and hard to click on.

If you want the inside of the undrawn circle to respond to clicks you can change the [pointer-events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property to say visible and the interior of the circle will then respond to clicks.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

var node = d3.select('g');
var addchild = node.append("circle")
   .attr("cx",320)
   .attr("cy",210)
   .attr("r",10)
   .attr("class","addchild")
   .style("fill","none")
      .style("pointer-events","visible")
   .style("stroke","#444");
   
   addchild.on("click", function() {
    alert("on click");
   });; 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="600" class="graph-container">
  <g>
    <rect x="150" y="190" height="50" width="200" rx="30" ry="30" nodeId="1" children="3" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(68, 68, 68);"></rect>
    <text x="250" y="220" text-anchor="middle" fill="#444" style="font-size: 24px;">root</text>

  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Alternately i can also choose to fill the circle with some color. Thanks for that information. Never knew `fill:none` is not clickable.

Comment: @SoorajChandran you certainly can but that would change what's drawn and wouldn't be as efficient if all you want is to respond to click events.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed a problem I had, with the 'click' event throwing an error and I couldn't figure out why and also it started breaking on other parts. Adding `.style("pointer-events","visible")` to the element really fixed it :)

Comment: You're a legend! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the problem is not with the click event, it is the `fill` style. Set it to `transparent` and your code will work.

```
        .style("fill","transparent")
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rmmbzk3a/5/

**One more tips.**

You can bind the `click` event when you create the element like this.

```
var addchild = node.append("circle")
            .attr("cx",320)
            .attr("cy",210)
            .attr("r",10)
            .attr("class","addchild")
            .style("fill","none")
            .style("stroke","#444")
            .on("click", function() {
                d3.select(this).style('fill', 'red'); //just to make sure
                alert("on click");
            });;
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rmmbzk3a/2/

Answer (score 1):

You click working but just your fill is none. So it's not working.

Else use rgba like `.style("fill","rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)")`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

var node = d3.select('g');
var addchild = node.append("circle")
   .attr("cx",320)
   .attr("cy",210)
   .attr("r",10)
   .attr("class","addchild")
   .style("fill","rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)")
   .style("stroke","#444")
    
       addchild.on("click", function() {
                alert("on click");
            });; 
 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="600" class="graph-container">
  <g>
    <rect x="150" y="190" height="50" width="200" rx="30" ry="30" nodeId="1" children="3" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(68, 68, 68);"></rect>
    <text x="250" y="220" text-anchor="middle" fill="#444" style="font-size: 24px;">root</text>
   
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmmbzk3a/4/)**